# Many to many with multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing the following columns:

seq_no | detail_no |user_id |guid_key

and another table with the following:

header| guid_key| date_entered| login_details| summary_transaction| trailer

Now I wish to map the two tables together such that the final answer is this way:

The first row should be value from header and subsequent rows should be values from seq_no, detail_no and user_id. There will be multiple rows of seq_no, detail_no and user_id. The last row should be the trailer.

The first table contains multiple rows that i need to be referenced to multiple rows in the second table. I'm new to SQL programming. I've looked up some many-many relationships but am unable to find an efficient way to do this. I am using a guid generator to write unique keys to both the tables. However, they key is not unique per row but rather a set of rows--> like for a set of data.

[image: This is how I want it to be]

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result as well. Formatted text, please. (I.e. no images...)

Comment: You need to specify HOW the two tables need to be referenced to one another. What columns in the two tables define that relationship?

Comment: the guid_key. I've edited my question such. :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not a presentation tool which is what you're trying to achieve here. You're also trying to make two results sets present as one result set (you want columns from table 1 on some rows on columns from table 2 on others). You could do something like this by

```
create table #temp (ID int identity(1,1), col1 varchar(200), col2 varchar(200) etc.)

insert into #temp col1, col2, etc values (select seq_no, guid_key, detail_no, user_id from table1)

insert into #temp col1, col2 etc. values (select seq_no, guid_key, header,  date_entered, login_details, summary_transaction from table1 inner join table2 on table1.guid_key = table2.guidkey where trailer is null)

insert into #temp col1, col2 etc. values (select seq_no, guid_key, trailer,  date_entered, login_details, summary_transaction from table1 inner join table2 on table1.guid_key = table2.guidkey where trailer is not null)

select * from #temp order by col1, ID
```

So you enter all the headers first followed by the detail, followed by the trailer. Thus when you order by seq_no and ID they will come out in the order desired.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me or perhaps my question was not framed correctly. I don't just want it presented. I want the data linked in that way too. I want data from the first table to be linked to data to the second table. But the problem is I want a set of rows from the first table to be linked to a set of rows to the second table so I can't use primary keys since that needs it to be unique. I'm using the guid generator to be unique for a set of rows. Not just one row.

Comment: Yeah I believe I've done what you've asked. Potentially you need to mock up sample data and sample results, then someone can help you find the transform/query to achieve it